# Boostrap popover content is not working when new post loading

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, autoload

We have a WordPress website on this website we publish articles every day. On this website, we are using the bootstrap popover and we loaded 4 posts(using autoload post plugin).

This bootstrap popover worked when the first article was displayed but when the second article display bootstrap popover not working. When we checked code(Inspect) popover id is changing but the bootstrap popover is not displayed.

Why popover is not working when 2nd and 3rd post is loading?

Please help with this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this in your javascript file for post.

```
$("body").popover({
        trigger: "click",
        selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]',
        container: '#your-post-list-outer-div-id',
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).